# Audio & Video not synchronized properly if i merged more videos in mp4parser

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-mediaplayer, mp4parser, audio-video-sync

I have used mp4parser for merging video with dynamic pause and record video capture for max 6 second recording. In preview its working fine when recorded video with minimum pause/record, If i tried with more than 3 pause/record mean the last video file not get merged properly with audio.At the start of the video the sync is ok but at the end the video hanged and audio playing in screen for the remaining file duration about 1sec.

My Recording manager

```
public class RecordingManager implements Camera.ErrorCallback, MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener, MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener {

    private static final String TAG = RecordingManager.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int FOCUS_AREA_RADIUS = 32;
    private static final int FOCUS_MAX_VALUE = 1000;
    private static final int FOCUS_MIN_VALUE = -1000;
    private static final long MINIMUM_RECORDING_TIME = 2000;
    private static final int MAXIMUM_RECORDING_TIME = 70 * 1000;
    private static final long LOW_STORAGE_THRESHOLD = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
    private static final long RECORDING_FILE_LIMIT = 100 * 1024 * 1024;

    private boolean paused = true;

    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = null;
    private boolean recording = false;

    private FrameLayout previewFrame = null;

    private boolean mPreviewing = false;

//    private TextureView mTextureView = null;
//    private SurfaceTexture mSurfaceTexture = null;
//    private boolean mSurfaceTextureReady = false;
//
    private SurfaceView surfaceView = null;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = null;
    private boolean surfaceViewReady = false;

    private Camera camera = null;
    private Camera.Parameters cameraParameters = null;
    private CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile = null;

    private int mOrientation = -1;
    private OrientationEventListener mOrientationEventListener = null;

    private long mStartRecordingTime;
    private int mVideoWidth;
    private int mVideoHeight;
    private long mStorageSpace;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
//    private Runnable mUpdateRecordingTimeTask = new Runnable() {
//        @Override
//        public void run() {
//            long recordingTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - mStartRecordingTime;
//            Log.d(TAG, String.format("Recording time:%d", recordingTime));
//            mHandler.postDelayed(this, CLIP_GRAPH_UPDATE_INTERVAL);
//        }
//    };
    private Runnable mStopRecordingTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            stopRecording();
        }
    };

    private static RecordingManager mInstance = null;
    private Activity currentActivity = null;
    private String destinationFilepath = "";
    private String snapshotFilepath = "";

    public static RecordingManager getInstance(Activity activity, FrameLayout previewFrame) {
        if (mInstance == null || mInstance.currentActivity != activity) {
            mInstance = new RecordingManager(activity, previewFrame);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    private RecordingManager(Activity activity, FrameLayout previewFrame) {
        currentActivity = activity;
        this.previewFrame = previewFrame;
    }

    public int getVideoWidth() {
        return this.mVideoWidth;
    }
    public int getVideoHeight() {
        return this.mVideoHeight;
    }
    public void setDestinationFilepath(String filepath) {
        this.destinationFilepath = filepath;
    }
    public String getDestinationFilepath() {
        return this.destinationFilepath;
    }
    public void setSnapshotFilepath(String filepath) {
        this.snapshotFilepath = filepath;
    }
    public String getSnapshotFilepath() {
        return this.snapshotFilepath;
    }
    public void init(String videoPath, String snapshotPath) {
        Log.v(TAG, "init.");
        setDestinationFilepath(videoPath);
        setSnapshotFilepath(snapshotPath);
        if (!Utils.isExternalStorageAvailable()) {
            showStorageErrorAndFinish();
            return;
        }

        openCamera();
        if (camera == null) {
            showCameraErrorAndFinish();
            return;
        }



    public void onResume() {
        Log.v(TAG, "onResume.");
        paused = false;

        // Open the camera
        if (camera == null) {
            openCamera();
            if (camera == null) {
                showCameraErrorAndFinish();
                return;
            }
        }

        // Initialize the surface texture or surface view
//        if (useTexture() && mTextureView == null) {
//            initTextureView();
//            mTextureView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//        } else if (!useTexture() && mSurfaceView == null) {
            initSurfaceView();
            surfaceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//        }

        // Start the preview
        if (!mPreviewing) {
            startPreview();
        }
    }

    private void openCamera() {
        Log.v(TAG, "openCamera");
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            camera.setErrorCallback(this);
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90); // Since we only support portrait mode
            cameraParameters = camera.getParameters();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            camera = null;
        }
    }

    private void closeCamera() {
        Log.v(TAG, "closeCamera");
        if (camera == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Already stopped.");
            return;
        }

        camera.setErrorCallback(null);
        if (mPreviewing) {
            stopPreview();
        }
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }




    private void initSurfaceView() {
        surfaceView = new SurfaceView(currentActivity);
        surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceViewCallback());
        surfaceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER);
        surfaceView.setLayoutParams(params);
        Log.d(TAG, "add surface view to preview frame");
        previewFrame.addView(surfaceView);
    }

    private void releaseSurfaceView() {
        if (surfaceView != null) {
            previewFrame.removeAllViews();
            surfaceView = null;
            surfaceHolder = null;
            surfaceViewReady = false;
        }
    }

    private void startPreview() {
//        if ((useTexture() && !mSurfaceTextureReady) || (!useTexture() && !mSurfaceViewReady)) {
//            return;
//        }

        Log.v(TAG, "startPreview.");
        if (mPreviewing) {
            stopPreview();
        }

        setCameraParameters();
        resizePreview();

        try {
//            if (useTexture()) {
//                mCamera.setPreviewTexture(mSurfaceTexture);
//            } else {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
//            }
            camera.startPreview();
            mPreviewing = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            closeCamera();
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "startPreview failed.");
        }

    }

    private void stopPreview() {
        Log.v(TAG, "stopPreview");
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            mPreviewing = false;
        }
    }

    public void onPause() {
        paused = true;

        if (recording) {
            stopRecording();
        }
        closeCamera();

//        if (useTexture()) {
//            releaseSurfaceTexture();
//        } else {
            releaseSurfaceView();
//        }
    }

    private void setCameraParameters() {
        if (CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P)) {
            camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P);
        } else if (CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P)) {
            camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P);
        } else {
            camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
        }
        mVideoWidth = camcorderProfile.videoFrameWidth;
        mVideoHeight = camcorderProfile.videoFrameHeight;
        camcorderProfile.fileFormat = MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4;
        camcorderProfile.videoFrameRate = 30;

        Log.v(TAG, "mVideoWidth=" + mVideoWidth + " mVideoHeight=" + mVideoHeight);
        cameraParameters.setPreviewSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);

        if (cameraParameters.getSupportedWhiteBalance().contains(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_AUTO)) {
            cameraParameters.setWhiteBalance(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_AUTO);
        }

        if (cameraParameters.getSupportedFocusModes().contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO)) {
            cameraParameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
        }

        cameraParameters.setRecordingHint(true);
        cameraParameters.set("cam_mode", 1);

        camera.setParameters(cameraParameters);
        cameraParameters = camera.getParameters();

        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
        Log.d(TAG, info.orientation + " degree");
    }

    private void resizePreview() {
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Video size:%d|%d", mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight));

        Point optimizedSize = getOptimizedPreviewSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Optimized size:%d|%d", optimizedSize.x, optimizedSize.y));

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams) previewFrame.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = optimizedSize.x;
        params.height = optimizedSize.y;
        previewFrame.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    public void setOrientation(int ori) {
        this.mOrientation = ori;
    }

    public void setOrientationEventListener(OrientationEventListener listener) {
        this.mOrientationEventListener = listener;
    }

    public Camera getCamera() {
        return camera;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public void setFocusArea(float x, float y) {
        if (camera != null) {
            int viewWidth = surfaceView.getWidth();
            int viewHeight = surfaceView.getHeight();

            int focusCenterX = FOCUS_MAX_VALUE - (int) (x / viewWidth * (FOCUS_MAX_VALUE - FOCUS_MIN_VALUE));
            int focusCenterY = FOCUS_MIN_VALUE + (int) (y / viewHeight * (FOCUS_MAX_VALUE - FOCUS_MIN_VALUE));
            final int left = focusCenterY - FOCUS_AREA_RADIUS < FOCUS_MIN_VALUE ? FOCUS_MIN_VALUE : focusCenterY - FOCUS_AREA_RADIUS;
            final int top = focusCenterX - FOCUS_AREA_RADIUS < FOCUS_MIN_VALUE ? FOCUS_MIN_VALUE : focusCenterX - FOCUS_AREA_RADIUS;
            final int right = focusCenterY + FOCUS_AREA_RADIUS > FOCUS_MAX_VALUE ? FOCUS_MAX_VALUE : focusCenterY + FOCUS_AREA_RADIUS;
            final int bottom = focusCenterX + FOCUS_AREA_RADIUS > FOCUS_MAX_VALUE ? FOCUS_MAX_VALUE : focusCenterX + FOCUS_AREA_RADIUS;

            Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFocusAreas(new ArrayList<Camera.Area>() {
                {
                    add(new Camera.Area(new Rect(left, top, right, bottom), 1000));
                }
            });
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAutoFocus");
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void startRecording(String destinationFilepath) {
        if (!recording) {
            updateStorageSpace();
            setDestinationFilepath(destinationFilepath);
            if (mStorageSpace <= LOW_STORAGE_THRESHOLD) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Storage issue, ignore the start request");
                Toast.makeText(currentActivity, "Storage issue, ignore the recording request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            if (!prepareMediaRecorder()) {
                Toast.makeText(currentActivity, "prepareMediaRecorder failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "Successfully prepare media recorder.");
            try {
                mediaRecorder.start();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "MediaRecorder start failed.");
                releaseMediaRecorder();
                return;
            }

            mStartRecordingTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if (mOrientationEventListener != null) {
                mOrientationEventListener.disable();
            }

            recording = true;
        }
    }

    public void stopRecording() {
        if (recording) {
            if (!paused) {
                // Capture at least 1 second video
                long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if (currentTime - mStartRecordingTime < MINIMUM_RECORDING_TIME) {
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mStopRecordingTask, MINIMUM_RECORDING_TIME - (currentTime - mStartRecordingTime));
                    return;
                }
            }

            if (mOrientationEventListener != null) {
                mOrientationEventListener.enable();
            }

//            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateRecordingTimeTask);

            try {
                mediaRecorder.setOnErrorListener(null);
                mediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(null);
                mediaRecorder.stop(); // stop the recording
                Toast.makeText(currentActivity, "Video file saved.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                long stopRecordingTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("stopRecording. file:%s duration:%d", destinationFilepath, stopRecordingTime - mStartRecordingTime));

                // Calculate the duration of video
                MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                mmr.setDataSource(this.destinationFilepath);
                String _length = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
                if (_length != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, String.format("clip duration:%d", Long.parseLong(_length)));
                }

                // Taking the snapshot of video
                Bitmap snapshot = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(this.destinationFilepath, Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(this.snapshotFilepath);
                    snapshot.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, out);
                    out.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

//                mActivity.showPlayButton();

            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                // if no valid audio/video data has been received when stop() is
                // called
            } finally {
//          

                releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
                if (!paused) {
                    cameraParameters = camera.getParameters();
                }
                recording = false;
            }

        }
    }

    public void setRecorderOrientation(int orientation) {
        // For back camera only
        if (orientation != -1) {
            Log.d(TAG, "set orientationHint:" + (orientation + 135) % 360 / 90 * 90);
            mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint((orientation + 135) % 360 / 90 * 90);
        }else {
            Log.d(TAG, "not set orientationHint to mediaRecorder");
        }
    }

    private boolean prepareMediaRecorder() {
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        camera.unlock();
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);

        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        mediaRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile);

        mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(MAXIMUM_RECORDING_TIME);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(this.destinationFilepath);

        try {
            mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(Math.min(RECORDING_FILE_LIMIT, mStorageSpace - LOW_STORAGE_THRESHOLD));
        } catch (RuntimeException exception) {
        }

        setRecorderOrientation(mOrientation);

        if (!useTexture()) {
            mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
        }

        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }

        mediaRecorder.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(this);

        return true;

    }

    private void releaseMediaRecorder() {
        if (mediaRecorder != null) {
            mediaRecorder.reset(); // clear recorder configuration
            mediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
            mediaRecorder = null;
            camera.lock(); // lock camera for later use
        }
    }

    private Point getOptimizedPreviewSize(int videoWidth, int videoHeight) {
        Display display = currentActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        Point optimizedSize = new Point();
        optimizedSize.x = size.x;
        optimizedSize.y = (int) ((float) videoWidth / (float) videoHeight * size.x);

        return optimizedSize;
    }

    private void showCameraErrorAndFinish() {
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener buttonListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                currentActivity.finish();
            }
        };
        new AlertDialog.Builder(currentActivity).setCancelable(false)
                .setTitle("Camera error")
                .setMessage("Cannot connect to the camera.")
                .setNeutralButton("OK", buttonListener)
                .show();
    }

    private void showStorageErrorAndFinish() {
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener buttonListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                currentActivity.finish();
            }
        };
        new AlertDialog.Builder(currentActivity).setCancelable(false)
                .setTitle("Storage error")
                .setMessage("Cannot read external storage.")
                .setNeutralButton("OK", buttonListener)
                .show();
    }

    private void updateStorageSpace() {
        mStorageSpace = getAvailableSpace();
        Log.v(TAG, "updateStorageSpace mStorageSpace=" + mStorageSpace);
    }

    private long getAvailableSpace() { 
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        Log.d(TAG, "External storage state=" + state);
        if (Environment.MEDIA_CHECKING.equals(state)) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            return -1;
        }

        File directory = currentActivity.getExternalFilesDir("vine");
        directory.mkdirs();
        if (!directory.isDirectory() || !directory.canWrite()) {
            return -1;
        }

        try {
            StatFs stat = new StatFs(directory.getAbsolutePath());
            return stat.getAvailableBlocks() * (long) stat.getBlockSize();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Fail to access external storage", e);
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private boolean useTexture() {
        return false;
//        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1;
    }

    private class SurfaceViewCallback implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            Log.v(TAG, "surfaceChanged. width=" + width + ". height=" + height);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            Log.v(TAG, "surfaceCreated");
            surfaceViewReady = true;
            surfaceHolder = holder;
            startPreview();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            Log.d(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed");
            surfaceViewReady = false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int error, Camera camera) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Camera onError. what=" + error + ".");
        if (error == Camera.CAMERA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED) {

        } else if (error == Camera.CAMERA_ERROR_UNKNOWN) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
        if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
            stopRecording();
        } else if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_REACHED) {
            stopRecording();
            Toast.makeText(currentActivity, "Size limit reached", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
        Log.e(TAG, "MediaRecorder onError. what=" + what + ". extra=" + extra);
        if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_ERROR_UNKNOWN) {
            stopRecording();
        }
    }

}
```

VideoUtils

```
public class VideoUtils {
    private static final String TAG = VideoUtils.class.getSimpleName();

    static double[] matrix = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 1.0 };

    public static boolean MergeFiles(String speratedDirPath,
            String targetFileName) {
        File videoSourceDirFile = new File(speratedDirPath);
        String[] videoList = videoSourceDirFile.list();
        List<Track> videoTracks = new LinkedList<Track>();
        List<Track> audioTracks = new LinkedList<Track>();
        for (String file : videoList) {
            Log.d(TAG, "source files" + speratedDirPath
                    + File.separator + file);
            try {
                FileChannel fc = new FileInputStream(speratedDirPath
                        + File.separator + file).getChannel();
                Movie movie = MovieCreator.build(fc);
                for (Track t : movie.getTracks()) {
                    if (t.getHandler().equals("soun")) {
                        audioTracks.add(t);
                    }
                    if (t.getHandler().equals("vide")) {

                        videoTracks.add(t);
                    }
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }

        Movie result = new Movie();

        try {
            if (audioTracks.size() > 0) {
                result.addTrack(new AppendTrack(audioTracks
                        .toArray(new Track[audioTracks.size()])));
            }
            if (videoTracks.size() > 0) {
                result.addTrack(new AppendTrack(videoTracks
                        .toArray(new Track[videoTracks.size()])));
            }
            IsoFile out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(result);



            FileChannel fc = new RandomAccessFile(
                    String.format(targetFileName), "rw").getChannel();

            Log.d(TAG, "target file:" + targetFileName);
            TrackBox tb = out.getMovieBox().getBoxes(TrackBox.class).get(1);

            TrackHeaderBox tkhd = tb.getTrackHeaderBox();
            double[] b = tb.getTrackHeaderBox().getMatrix();

            tkhd.setMatrix(matrix);

            fc.position(0);
            out.getBox(fc);
            fc.close();
            for (String file : videoList) {
                File TBRFile = new File(speratedDirPath + File.separator + file);
                TBRFile.delete();
            }
            boolean a = videoSourceDirFile.delete();
            Log.d(TAG, "try to delete dir:" + a);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static boolean clearFiles(String speratedDirPath) {
        File videoSourceDirFile = new File(speratedDirPath);
        if (videoSourceDirFile != null
                && videoSourceDirFile.listFiles() != null) {
            File[] videoList = videoSourceDirFile.listFiles();
            for (File video : videoList) {
                video.delete();
            }
            videoSourceDirFile.delete();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static int createSnapshot(String videoFile, int kind, String snapshotFilepath) {
        return 0;
    };

    public static int createSnapshot(String videoFile, int width, int height, String snapshotFilepath) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

my reference code project link is

https://github.com/jwfing/AndroidVideoKit

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented an alternative solution to achieve the same result.
Instead of creating multiple files to implement vine like pause and record functionality in android, 
I have created 2 separate recorder and managed the time-stamp.

Here is the Library code:

https://github.com/sourab-sharma/TouchToRecord

Comment: Hi Saurab, I have use your code, its working completely but, when i record half video in portrait mode with rear camera and half video with front camera in portrait mode then half video from front camera is showing upside down, can you please give me some solution on this

Comment: Give me your file in which you have made changes to make camera view  in portrait mode. I will check it and fix it for you.

Comment: I have just added android:orientation="portrait" in mainfest file , i have changed nothing

Comment: Buddy I am preparing for an interview on Monday, I will try to find the time if I can otherwise I promise to get it done on Tuesday.

Comment: Hi saurab,hi sourab, i want to execute rotate function thorugh ffmpeg in your code i have applied this
public static int RotateVideo(Context paramContext, String input, String output)
{
return (new Processor(getEncodingLibraryPath(paramContext), paramContext)).newCommand().addInputPath(input).filterRotation(1).setCopy().processToOutput(output);
}
public Processor filterRotation(int paramInt1)
{
this.mFilters.add("transpose=1");
return this;
}can you suggest me hoe to apply rotation command though your code

Answer (score 0):

First, it looks like the recorder fails to start.

Then you are trying to stop a video that has never been prepared or started, which is telling you "stop called in state 0". I suppose you are trying to play the video that failed to record. You should call `isPlaying` to check if the video is actually playing before calling `stopPlayback`.

Comment: Yeah @dave,  i have mentioned the same as my error is in video playback. I have cleared this with by changing the frame rate value as 30 from 25.